# jshint: enforcing "globalstrict" : false when "node" : true

Tags: jshint

In my .jshintrc file I have `globalstrict` set to false and `node` set to true.  A side affect of this is that is appears to suppress the warnings I would expect if a global `use strict` was in place.

Is there any way of overriding this behaviour so that the warning is not suppressed?

***Edit***

Having re-read the docs on jshint.com and some of the issues on GitHub (notably #1922 and #2551) I have modified my `.jshintrc` as follows:

```
{
  "bitwise": true,
  "curly": true,
  "debug": false,
  "eqeqeq": true,
  "forin": true,
  "freeze": true,
  "futurehostile": true,
  "globalstrict": false,
  "latedef": true,
  "noarg": true,
  "nonbsp": true,
  "nonew": true,
  "singleGroups": true,
  "strict": true,
  "undef": true,
  "unused": "strict",

  "browser": false,
  "devel": false,

  "node": true,

  "predef": [
    "-console"
  ],

  "+W097": true
}
```

However this doesn't work for this particular message (it does though if, for example, I change it to -W034, which is the functional equivalent).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This currently isn't possible however issue #2575 and associated pull request #2576 will provide the functionality if they are accepted.